# Is there a way to transfer a value from one function to the main function for a loop?

Tags: c, function, for-loop

I am writing a banking program for an assignment. I made a base program that has no functions. Now I need to add two functions to replace to parts of the code. I am choosing to replace the user input loops for deposit and withdrawal amounts. I can make the function work fine with asking for the number, but when I attempt to use a loop asking for deposit amounts it is not working properly. I think my loop limiting variable does not transfer due to it coming from another function. Is there a way to get that limiting variable. I have included the portions of code that is involved.

```
int deposit_message (void)
{
    int d;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number of deposits (0-5): ");
        scanf("%i", &d);

        /* Define rules for invalid answers */
        /* -------------------------------- */

        if( d < 0 || d > 5)
        {
            printf("*** Invalid number of deposits, please re-enter.");
        }
    }while( d < 0 || d > 5); /* end of loop */
    return d;
} /* end of function */

/* Prompt user for positive deposits, if invalid re-prompt. */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------- */

    for( i=0; i < d; i++)
    {
                                            /* Create array for deposits */
        do
        {
            printf("Enter the amount of deposit #%i: ", i +1);
            scanf("%f", &deposit[i]);

            /* Define rules for invalid answers */
            /* -------------------------------- */

            if(deposit[i] < 0.00)
            {
                printf("*** Deposit amount must be greater than zero, please re-enter.\n");
            }

        }while(deposit[i] < 0.00);
```

```
Revised code after attempting to pass the variable d. 
void deposit_message (int d)
{

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the number of deposits (0-5): ");
        scanf("%i", &d);

        /* Define rules for invalid answers */
        /* -------------------------------- */

        if( d < 0 || d > 5)
        {
            printf("*** Invalid number of deposits, please re-enter.");
        }
    }while( d < 0 || d > 5); /* end of loop */
    return d;
} /* end of function */


    /* Prompt user for number of deposits between 0 and 5 with function, if invalid re-prompt with loop. */
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    deposit_message(&d);

/* Prompt user for positive deposits, if invalid re-prompt. */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------- */

    for( i=0; i < d; i++)
    {
                                            /* Create array for deposits */
        do
        {
            printf("Enter the amount of deposit #%i: ", i +1);
            scanf("%f", &deposit[i]);

            /* Define rules for invalid answers */
            /* -------------------------------- */

            if(deposit[i] < 0.00)
            {
                printf("*** Deposit amount must be greater than zero, please re-enter.\n");
            }

        }while(deposit[i] < 0.00);
```

The loop should ask for a deposit amount X times based on the number of deposits chosen by the user. When used, it would either not stop, or just once. (After attempting to revise it, the loop does not stop.

Comment: `Is there a way to transfer a value from one function to the main function for a loop?` - return value or pointer passed as function parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass reference of variable **d** defined in **main()** method to **deposit_message()**, like shown below.

```
void deposit_message(int* d){
    // take value of deposits from user
    scanf("%d",d);
 }

 int main(){
    int d; 
    deposit_message(&d);

    //  your code here...
    //  your loop 
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
        // logic here
    }
 }
```

Comment: I did what you said, but the loop does not stop at the number inputted by the user.

Comment: Your deposit_message(int* d)  should be like this because you are sending a reference, so you should receive it in pointer. Second where ever you have used d in deposit_message(int* d), you should use *d because it is a pointer.

Comment: Okay, once I added in the * to all of the d's, it started working. Thank You!